# Generate PDF for iPhone using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova

I know this is not a part of Phonegap API but iOS has this ability

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

How do I do this in Phonegap for iPhone? I am new so if you can point 
me how to setup the file for this or how to link Phonegap to work with 
this API, that would be great. I am flexible in different ways:

1. Draw into PDF OR generate html then turn into PDF
2. Build a plug in for Phonegap to call iOS API OR

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have Objective C knowledge, implement it as a phonegap plugin (platform dependient). Follow this guide:

http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2010/04/01/iphonegap-plugs/

Answer (score 0):

I think there a couple of different options in terms of solutions, however, as it stands right now you can't do it with the PhoneGap (as is).  PhoneGap has pretty limited-iOS hooks, just some of the basics.

If you know Cocoa/Objective-C, you could create the API-access and integrate with PhoneGap.  Depending on what your PDF contains, you could also create the PDF remotely, etc..

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to generate PDF somewhere else? Because I don't want to do that in my server. I know this requires API-access integrate with Phonegap with I don't know how...

Comment: Do you mean like a public API or something?

Comment: Yah public API that Apple releases for PDF generation. I am actually opened to use server PDF generation too if that comes to the last resort.